# Доступность портов ipv6

Tags: роутер, ipv6, openwrt, порты

Перепрошил роутер на OpenWrt и заработал ipv6.

Насколько я понимаю, теперь все порты подключенных устройств доступны через ipv6 из интернета. Как перенастроить, чтобы работало так же, как для ipv4?

Под так же я подразумеваю, что по умолчанию порты не доступны, но можно либо явно на роутере выставить проброс, либо это может сделать использующая данный порт программа.

Или же есть причины так не поступать? А то как-то страшновато...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как оказалось, я ошибся.

Роутер с OpenWrt уже содержит встроенный файрволл, который блокирует запросы к ipv6-адресам из внешней сети, но при этом порты открыты для всех устройств локальной.

Поскольку ipv6-адрес одинаков для внешней и локальной сетей, а я проверял по тому же принципу, что с ipv4 - просто с другого (а иногда и того же самого) устройства, моя проверка оказалась неправильной.

Теперь буду узнавать наоборот - [как пробросить порт.](//ru.stackoverflow.com/q/927984/178988)